# How to get the url of a frame?

Tags: html, url, frames

This question has been asked before, but the answer did not address the problem I face after resolving it to a certain degree:

I have a simple HTML page with 2 frames, in the left one I am opening some URLs, and in the right one have text input boxes where I need onClick to get current URL of the document opened in the left frame. Here is my code for the text box:

```
<input type="TEXT" name="proz" onClick=value=top.left_frame_name.location.href>
```

The problem is that it works when I have a local file opened in the left frame, I get
file:///C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/Mihailo/My%20Documents/furniture/dnevnaI.htm
when I click on the text box,
but if I open some outside link http://... in the left frame, clicking in the text box in the right frame produces nothing in the box, but message in the browser (error : Permission denied).

The application is a wishlist page, where on the left user is opening product pages from another domain, and on the right they have my page with a form with several text boxes where I would like the user to click in boxes to memorize URLs of chosen products, and at the end to be able to send their choices to me.

Comment: You cannot access the frame if it is not hosted on the same domain.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you use iframe on the right? why not just use a div if all you need is to display some DOM elements like textboxes?

Comment: @ComFreek: so there is no way to get an URL of the document from another domain?

Comment: @Blaise: I never said I use iframe, I am a naive HTML programmer from the 1990s, when iframe did not exist. How would I use div in a document that is not from my domain? I will further explained above what the application I am trying to write needs to do.

Comment: @user2824969 That is correct, there is **no** way. You can only get the first URI which you assigned via HTML or JS, but there is **no** way of determining to which sites the user surfed by clicking links.

Comment: Did you mean <frame> or <iframe>?

Comment: @reporter: I was using frames, not iframe

Comment: @ComFreek: many say that there is no way, but then how do data mining software and search engines extract URLs and meta tags from pages that are obviously from another domains? If extracting URL is impossible, I would be happy if extracting meta tags would be possible. How?

Comment: @user2824969 These are totally different concepts. Search engines send a request from **their servers** to external servers, so they get the HTML source code. You are on the client side and you want the content of a cross-domain frame. You can also send AJAX requests to external domains in JS, but only if the foreign servers respond with a CORS header.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this

You can communicate with frames though, using `postMessage` but you need to change a source of a page you are "talking" with ;)

http://viget.com/extend/using-javascript-postmessage-to-talk-to-iframes

The best way I can think of to solve this problem is to create a bookmarklet which will send information to your page

It can look like this:

```
javascript:(function(i){i.src='http://yoursite.com/post.jpg?page='+encodeURIComponent(document.location.href)+'&time='+(+new Date);i.onload=function(){ alert('ok, keep going') }})(new Image)
```

Use of an image will allow sending cross-domain messages. Just make user to drag link with this code into his bookmarks and click on it on every page.

Or just make a plugin for browsers